# When did the Pentium II come out?

Tags: history, intel-pentium

Wikipedia says it came out in 1997, but [this site](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium-II/index.html) says it came out in 1995.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Intel says 1997](http://download.intel.com/pressroom/kits/IntelProcessorHistory.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Out of the two I would trust Wikipedia - They provide more detail regarding the date (an exact day), and I have never heard of the other site.

The PII may have been designed in '95 but not released to the public until '97.